# ReSharper and Rational Team Concert (RTC) - Do they play nicely together?

Tags: version-control, resharper, rtc

I have recently joined a small development team that is considering a new version control system. As it is part of a large organisation, we are likely to adopt the company standard of Rational Team Concert.

I have recommended that they should choose something much simpler, but I will probably not get my way.

I have a major concern that it will not play nicely with ReSharper, and will force me to change the way I work. I use ReSharper quite heavily to perform refactoring and have it create and move files for me.

Will I be able to do this with RTC? What is the friction like?

As a footnote, the team is currently using ClearCase (clearly suckers for punishment), and my ability to do refactoring is severely hampered. I cannot even create project folders and move files from within Visual Studio, let alone have ReSharper do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReSharper shouldn't interfere with your Version Control software in any way.

I've used ClearCase with ReSharper in the past and didn't notice any friction. The only thing that I can think of is that you were using the ClearCase plugin for Visual Studio in which case I would advise you to stop.

As long as you use the Source Control application for checkins/checkouts/commits/etc, you should be good to go.

Comment: Yes, I am using the plugin for ClearCase ... I tried to avoid it when I joined the team and for some reason could not get it to work without. Thanks for the tip, I will have another attempt.

Answer (score 1):

I've used ReSharper and RTC together for the better part of a year.  RTC hasn't interfered with ReSharper in any way I can recall.