# Clearcase does not checkout project files when files are moved by resharper

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, resharper, clearcase

My current project is under source control by clearcase. I am also using Resharper 8.1 with Visual Studio 2012. I am also using a VS integration for ClearCase.

When adding files manually to a project (by right clicking on the Project -> `Add`-> `Class`), ClearCase checks out the project file, so that saving all files works like a charm.

"Unfortunatelly", I tend to use a lot of the ReSharper functionallity. When using ReSharpers `Move To` command, it seems that ClearCase prevents ReSharper (or Visual Studio) to check out the project files. They are modified, but cannot be saved - I always get that `Save As` dialogue when saving all documents. To get this working, i need to *manually* check out the *.proj file and *then* save the modified files. Is there a way to automatically check out those files?

Another problem is when using ReSharpers `Rename`: I just tried to use `Rename` on an interface that is used in approx. 60 other files. Everythink worked, except that the files were not checked out by clearcase! In order to save, I needed to Save all, click cancel for the first file (ClearCase then recognizes that the file has been modified and checks it out) and then save *again*. This is really annoying and prevents from a produtive workflow..

Comment: Strange, as it differs from http://stackoverflow.com/a/6364454/6309

Comment: Indeed. Any help is apprechiated - maybe there are some super fancy, hidden options to enable this feature? All the productivity boost provided by resharper is gone with this mess.

Comment: What version of clearCase are you using?